# Groupby and sort the values in dict in Python

Tags: python, sorting, group-by

I have a dictionary as follows in python and I have to group by 'label' and get the highest value of 'confidence' for each 'label'

```
[{'label': 'id',
  'confidence': 0.11110526,
  'topleft': {'x': 0, 'y': 0},
  'bottomright': {'x': 187, 'y': 57}},

{'label': 'id',
  'confidence': 0.10690566,
  'topleft': {'x': 265, 'y': 0},
  'bottomright': {'x': 525, 'y': 54}},

 {'label': 'name',
  'confidence': 0.15541315,
  'topleft': {'x': 9, 'y': 24},
  'bottomright': {'x': 116, 'y': 58}},

 {'label': 'group',
  'confidence': 0.12578075,
  'topleft': {'x': 53, 'y': 24},
  'bottomright': {'x': 153, 'y': 61}},

 {'label': 'name',
  'confidence': 0.12709439,
  'topleft': {'x': 0, 'y': 0},
  'bottomright': {'x': 247, 'y': 84}},

 {'label': 'group',
  'confidence': 0.116156094,
  'topleft': {'x': 96, 'y': 23},
  'bottomright': {'x': 191, 'y': 61}}]
```

How do I achieve this efficiently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `groupby`

```
for n,g in groupby(tst,key=lambda x:x['label']):
     print n,max(list(g),key=lambda x:x['confidence']).get('confidence')
```

Result:

```
id 0.11110526
name 0.15541315
group 0.12578075
name 0.12709439
group 0.116156094
```